# Stop audio player from restarting music after a phone call

Tags: calls, music-player

Whenever I receive a phone while listening music (with earplugs), I disconnect the earplugs and take the phone through the normal speakers.

The music is paused during the phone call, no problem there, but when I hang up, the music starts again, even without the earplugs. Which is kind of annoying at work, in an open space.

Is there a way to force the music to stay paused after the phone call?

I'm using the [Music Mod](http://www.appbrain.com/app/music-mod-(froyo-only)/com.piratemedia.musicmod) app on an Froyo-powered HTC Legend, but I believe it has happened to me with every music player I've tried.

Comment: do your earplugs not have microphone?

Comment: @Lie they do, but I don't like using them to make a phone call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is the [headset blocker widget](http://www.appbrain.com/app/headset-blocker/com.idunnolol.headsetblocker) - install it and then put it up on your home screen as a widget and then toggle it ON.

Now, whenever you unplug your headphones, the music player will stop playing. try it and see if it works.

BTW, [Meridian Player](http://www.appbrain.com/app/meridian-media-player-autonomy/org.iii.romulus.meridian) has an in-built option to disallow resuming playback after a phone call.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Autostarts app to edit the end-phone-call event and remove your music app from the list of apps that get alerted on that event.  I believe it requires root.

Comment: AFAIK this could be done with Tasker even without root.